# linear functional and inner product

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Currently, I'm studying the relationship btw linear functional and inner product, and this is the associated theorem in Stein's Real Analysis. (theorem 5.3, chapter 4)

[image]

I understand all of the proofs, except for the red line $||l|| = ||g||$. I'm not sure how the equality holds. I tried to apply Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $|(l(f)| = |(f,g)| \le ||f||||g||$, but I failed to extend to the conclusion.

Any idea about this question would be grateful. Thank you.

For reference, let me write the definition of some concepts in Stein's book.

A linear operator $T : H_1 \to H_2$ is **bounded** if there is $M > 0$ such that $||T(f)||_{H_2} \le M||f||_{H_1}$ $\forall f \in H_1$

The **norm** of $T$ is defined by $||T|| = inf\{M\; |\; ||T(f)||_{H_2} \le M||f||_{H_1}\}$

**Lemma 5.1** $||T|| = sup\{|(T(f), g) \;|\;||f|| \le 1,\; ||g|| \le 1,\; f \in H_1, g \in H_2 \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g \neq 0$. $|\ell (f)| \leq \|f\|\|g\|$ so $\|\ell\|\leq \|g\|$. Also, $\ell (\frac g {\|g\|}) =\langle \frac g {\|g\|}, g \rangle =\|g\|$ and $\|\frac g {\|g\|}\|=1$ so $\|\ell \|\geq \|g\|$. The case $g=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Is the latter the application of lemma 5.1 of chapter 4? $||l|| \ge |(l(g/||g||), 1)| = |(||g||,1)| = ||g||$ This is my understanding of your comments. and I added the lemma 5.1 on my question just in case.

Comment: @jason1 Yes, I am using Lemma 5.1 In fact, norm of an operator is usually **defined** as in Lemma 5.1 ( as  a supremum instead of an infimum).